# Required Field Validator in code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am trying to use required field validator in code behind file but it is showing the following error.

Error:

> Unable to find control id 'TextBox1' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'abcd854'

Note: TextBox1 exists in the page; I have tested it.

[image]

Aspx Page

```
  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="save" />       
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Cs File

```
   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //RequiredFieldValidator validator = ControlsValidation.AssignRequiredFieldValidatorToControl(TextBox1, "Field is required", "*", "save");
            //validator.ControlToValidate = ((TextBox)this.Form.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("TextBox1")).ID;


            RequiredFieldValidator validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
            validator.ID = "abcd" + new Random().Next(100, 1000);
            validator.ControlToValidate = ((TextBox)this.Form.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("TextBox1")).ID;
            validator.EnableClientScript = true;
            validator.ErrorMessage = "";
            validator.Text = "*";
            validator.ValidationGroup = "save";
            validator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;

            this.Controls.Add(validator);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting textbox id mode to static

Comment: did not work . hard luck

Comment: remove ID portion when you find the control ((TextBox)this.Form.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("TextBox1"));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was:

```
 this.Controls.Add(validator);
```

As we all can see, `TextBox1` is in child page, meaning "`Content Page`", so when using the above line of code, it adds the control in the master page, in which there is no control with the id "`TextBox1`".

After replacing the above line of code with:

```
this.Form.FindControl("MainContent").Controls.Add(validator);
```

it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, after rendering your page, the TextBox's id will be changed (see source code in browser). you can change its client id mode to static so that it won't change.

`Add ClientIDMode="Static"` in your textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

Code behind

```
oTexbox1.Attributes["required"] = "true";
```

Comment: This works but how to add the error message and any other property to it like adding css etc?

Answer (score -2):

Try using ClientID instead of ID

```
RequiredFieldValidator validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
validator.ID = "abcd" + new Random().Next(100, 1000);

validator.ControlToValidate = ((TextBox)this.Form
             .FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("TextBox1")).ClientID;

validator.EnableClientScript = true;
validator.ErrorMessage = "";
validator.Text = "*";
validator.ValidationGroup = "save";
validator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;

this.Controls.Add(validator);
```